# How do finance professionals procounce "CECL"?

Tags: terminology

I am interviewing for a financial company that models risk and is working to be prepared for the upcoming compliances changes regarding CECL (current expected credit loss).

I've been doing research on CECL to prepare for the interview, but I can't find anywhere on the internet: **how do finance professionals pronounce the word CECL**?

Comment: *Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the following links, it is commonly pronounced "Cecil".

https://kaufmanrossin.com/blog/bank-ready-meet-cecil/

> The proposed model introduces the concept of shifting from an incurred
>   loss model to the current expected credit loss model commonly referred
>   to as CECL (pronounced “Cecil”).

http://www.gonzobanker.com/2016/02/cecl-the-blind-leading-the-blurry/

> [...] and its name is CECL (Current Estimated Credit Losses, pronounced like
>   the name “Cecil”).
>
> The name Cecil means “blind,” which is ironic, because FASB’s upcoming
>   guidance will push FIs to clarify the future performance of their loan
>   portfolios by using models to predict CECL of all loan portfolios.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/operational-financial-impact-cecl-banks-nikhil-deshmukh

> Termed as Current Expected Credit Loss (CECL, or Cecil, as some call
>   it), [...]

Comment: Thank you so much for doing this research.  I swear I could have looked all day and not found it!

Comment: @user1717828 You're welcome. That's how I assumed it was pronounced, so just did a search for CECL Cecil. Good luck with the interview.